# extract_first() and extract() methods on Scrapy selectors are not returning the same value

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to collect data from a cinema webpage.

Working with the XPath selectors, if I use the selectors with the extract() method, as such:

```
def parse_with_extract(self, response):
    div = response.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-7 col-md-9']/p[@class='movie__option']")
    data = i.xpath("text()").extract()
    return data
```

It returns:

[image: Result of extract() on selectors]

If I use the selector with the extract_first() method as such:

```
def parse_with_extract_first(self, response):
    div = response.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-7 col-md-9']/p[@class='movie__option']")
    storage = []
    for i in div:
        data = i.xpath("text()").extract_first()
        storage.append(data)
    return storage
```

It returns:

[image: Result of extract_first() on selectors]

Why is the extract() method returning all characters, including the "\xa0", and the extract_first() method returning an empty string instead?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: @StasDeep [Here is the link](http://www.genesiscinemas.com/portharcourt.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closer at the response, you'll see that `@class=movie__option` element looks like this:

```
'<p class="movie__option" style="color: #000;">\n                                    <strong>Thursday 3rd of May 2018:</strong>\n                                    11:20am\xa0 \xa0  \n                                </p>'
```

If you extract `text()` of this element you basically get two strings: one which is before `strong` tag and one which is after (`text()` takes only first-level text):

```
['\n                                    ',
 '\n                                    11:20am\xa0 \xa0  \n                                ']
```

What `extract_first` does is just taking the first of these two strings:

```
'\n                                    '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as of your output, which looks something like the following:

```
['\n                                    ',
 '\n                                    11:20am\xa0 \xa0  \n                                ']
```

contains two strings.

My suggestions for everyone who is getting the same data in return like new lines and empty space, use Python's built-in method strip(). This method applies to a string. So, you can apply this method by following:

> data = response.xpath("//path/to/your/data").get().strip()

This will make your output looks something like this:

```
'11:20am'
```

Also, have a look at what's the difference between extract() and extract_first().

1. ```
   extract()
   ```

This method returns the list. This is an old method in Scrapy. The method used nowadays, instead of extract(), is getall(). It's the same as extract().

> extract()   -- updated to -->   getall()

Now let’s take a look at extract_first() method

2. ```
   extract_first()
   ```

This method returns the str instead of the list. This is also an old method in Scrapy. The method used nowadays, instead of extract_first(), is get().

> extract_first()   -- updated to -->   get()